# Resizing HTML Video to be consistent size

Tags: javascript, html, css, resize, html5-video

I am trying to resize my video to keep the same aspect on all screen sizes. Currently if I resize my screen it will shrink the box down and it will lose the size I want. My goal is to have the video stay the same width and height in aspect to the screen size.

#### This is an example of what I am trying to do to the video when the window is resized:

[image]

#### Currently this is how my JavaScript looks for collecting all the videos and then iterating through them to calculate the aspect:

```
resizeVideo() {
    let windowWidth = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth,
        windowHeight = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.body.clientHeight;
    let windowAspectRatio = windowHeight / windowWidth;
    // Get each video
    let videos = document.getElementsByTagName('video');

    // iterate through each video to resize and keep the same aspect
    for (let i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {
        let video = videos[i];
        let videoWidth = video.videoWidth;
        let videoHeight = video.videoHeight;
        let videoAspectRatio = videoHeight / videoWidth;

        console.log(video.width + " " + video.height);
        console.log(windowHeight + " " + windowWidth);

        // compare window height vs window width
        if (windowHeight < windowWidth) {
            // window height is less than window width
            video.width = window.innerWidth * .95;
        } else {
            // window height it greater than window width
            video.height = window.innerHeight * .95;
        }

    }
}
```

#### Here is my CSS for how I structure my HTML:

```
.carousel { // carousel will be 100% width and height
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    .carousel-content { // Content
        display: block;

        .project { // Each project will take up 100% of the screen
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100vh;

            .video-container { // Container will contain video
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;


                video { // Calculate video width, and height with javascript
                    display: block;
                    margin: auto;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As in, when you resize it, it stays the height you want, keeps the initial ration you set, but the rest of the video just gets cut off?

Comment: I would rather have it stretched and centered. If you go to http://samsy.ninja/ and click on the enter you can see how he resizes his videos and that is what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Padding is the way to go, because vertical padding is calculated based on width, so you can use it to create a consistent ratio.

The setup is Parent Container -> Sizing Container -> absolutely
 positioned video with 100% height and width.

**(view code sample full screen to test)**

```css
#VideoOuter {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
 }
.sizing-div {
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 33%;
  height: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  position: relative;
 }
 #Video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: aliceblue;
font-size: 20px;
 }
```

```html
<div id="VideoOuter">
  <div class="sizing-div">
    <div id="Video" class="constant-ratio">I'm a video</div>
  </div>
</div>
```